# React cannot refer changes of one var to another var in a nested object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I face a struggle to use outter variable state inside a nested object.

for example lets say I have those two states:

```
const [type, setType] = useState('line');
const [options, setOptions] = useState({
id: 1,
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function () {
      let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
      let chart = this;
      for(let btntmp of btn) {
        if(btntmp.id=='area' || btntmp.id=='pie' || btntmp.id=='bar' || btntmp.id=='line' || btntmp.id=='column') {
          btntmp.addEventListener('click', () => {
            Type = btntmp.id;
            //setType(Type);
          //  
          
          for(let i=0;i<chart.series.length;i++) {
            chart.series[i].update({ type: Type});
          }
          });
          chart.redraw();
        }

       
      }   
    },
  },
  type: type,
},});


setType('bar');
useEffect(() => {

console.log(options.chart.type); ---> prints 'line'

if (type == 'pie') {
  console.log('its pie');
  setEndPeriodSelected(null);
  setShown(false);
} else {
  setShown(true);
  
}    
},[type]);
```

While running the code, type will get a default value of 'line' and when setType is called, type is changed but options.chart.type doesnt get its new value.

I've already came up with a solution of spreading options and then just change its type all by using setOptions(). but isn't suppose to be direct change by changing type only?

Looking forward for help.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think its necessary to have duplicated data. delete the `type` key in the `chart` object.

anyway, you can set the options in useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {

  setOptions({...options, chart: {...options.chart, type}};

  // ... your code ... //

},[type]);
```

Comment: Hi  Yinon, it's obvious that duplicated data is not necessary, that wasn't my question. all I'm asking is, is it possible to make change on one state and it will influence another by the way I described. 
as mentioned (I already found the solution of setOptions as an answer to my problem, but not an answer to my question)